# unable to build twitter/scalding project from github

Tags: scala, sbt, scalding

I am new to scala, sbt and scalding.
I cloned the twitter/scalding project from github , downloaded sbt MSI on windows , installed it and ran "sbt compile" from project's home folder.
I run into issues with slf4j related error bieng thrown at compile time with absolutely no changes done from my end.

> [error] (scalding/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved
>   dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.6: several problems occurred
>   while resolving dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.6
>   {test=[default(compile)]}: [error]         several problems occurred
>   while resolving dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-parent;1.6.6 {}: [error]
>   URI has an authority component

Would appreciate any pointers on what could be wrong.
None of the solutions available online have helped so far.

Comment: Cannot confirm on Linux with sbt version 0.13.8

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to install sbt yourself... you can use the one bundled with Scalding repo. As suggested here https://github.com/twitter/scalding#building you just run ./sbt which is this one: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/sbt 

Haven't tried it on windows though.